# How to Iterate a Join Query in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

So this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DBContext_Model db = new DBContext_Model();
            var srmas = (
                            from SRMAs in db.SRMAs
                            join SRMAStatus in db.SRMAStatus on SRMAs.Id equals SRMAStatus.Id
                            join PurchaseOrders in db.PurchaseOrders on SRMAs.PONumber equals PurchaseOrders.PONumber
                            join Suppliers in db.Suppliers on PurchaseOrders.SupplierID equals Suppliers.SupplierID
                            select new {SRMAs.Id,SRMAs.PONumber,SRMAs.CreatedOn,Suppliers.SupplierName,SRMAStatus.StatusName,PurchaseOrders.PODate,PurchaseOrders.suppliersOrderNumber}
                        ).ToList();
            ViewBag.SRMAs = srmas;
            return View();
        }
```

Now I need to iterate the result. What type should I use to cast my loop variable to fetch desire field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have an annonymous type list from this query. You can't cast to an annonymous type because it only exists in runtime.

The best way to overcome this is to create a ViewModel class. A persistence ignorant class that it's only purpose is data transfer:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public int SRMAsId { get; set; }
    public int PONumber { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

With this you can select new instances of this class:

```
ViewBag.SRMAs = srmas.Select(srma => new IndexViewModel
                                     {
                                         SRMAsId = srma.Id,
                                         PONumber = srma.PONumber,
                                         // ...
                                     }).ToList();
```